# Entity Framework Core (SQL) and lookup table (junction table) caching

Tags: sql, caching, entity-framework-core

I found a lot of similar questions but I've been annoyed by this for some time now.

So let's say I have a tables (simplified):

```
Currency:
 - Name (USD, EUR)
 - SomeCurrencySpecificStuff

Balance:
 - CurrencyId
 - Currency (navigation property)
 - Amount (actual balance)
 - UserId
 - User (navigation)
```

So the basic setup where each user has it's own Balance that is always referenced to a Currency. Balance changes often but Currency does not.

If I just include the reference data with `user...Include(x => x.Balances).ThenInclude(x => x.Currency)` it translates into complicated SQL query with JOINS that I don't think you're able to cache globally, only for this user? I'm assuming that the SQL query that is shown in the logs is actually performed and not somehow retrieved from EF 1st level cache?

If I try to manually query the Currency as a single query (to make 2nd level cache work) and set it to the Balance object the codes becomes messy and change tracking gets totally f***ed. You **sometimes** get a bunch of errors as it tries to add new Currency with same ID so you have to manually disable the change tracking, which becomes very messy code again.

How can I achieve this generically and easily, so it's easy to do in the future as this kind of stuff is regularly needed? If I have 1000 clients doing Balance requests I should not have to do 1000 queries to Currency table. These reference tables are generally very small (<100 rows) but surely it adds a lot of overhead as the requests grow.

To be clear I'm not looking for caching solution per se (I'm probably going with Redis and EF 2nd level cache) but how to "enable" the cache in the first place for my situation.